# Implemented methods are not working in native interface(android) for Fused location provider

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to apply FusedLocation provider in cn1 through native interface(android). I've implemented ConnectionCallbacks and OnConnectionFailedListener interfaces. It generates methods like onConnected(), onConnectionSuspended() and onConnectionFailed() in native android, which are not working when app is built in cn1.

Moreover, lifecycle methods like onResume, onDestroy of FusedLocationImpl etc are also not working. In the coming days, I'm planning to create the fused GPS library for general purpose as well.

PS. There are no build errors and got no any other errors when debugged.

FusedLocationImpl.java

```
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

public class FusedLocationImpl implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener  {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    public void getFusedLocationPermission() {
       if (!com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, "Please allow location permission")) {
       }
    }

    public void fusedLocation() {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) { // not working...
        Log.i("onConnected", "GoogleApiClient connected!");
        createLocationRequest();
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i("onConnected", " Location: " + mLastLocation);
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() { // not working...
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(final LocationResult locationResult) {
                Log.i("onLocationResult",locationResult + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
                Log.i("onLocationAvailability", "onLocationAvailability: isLocationAvailable =  " + locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
            }
        }, null);
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i("onConnectionFailed", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    public void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (LocationListener) this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    public void onStart() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.i("onStart", "mGoogleApiClient.connect()");
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("onDestory", "Service destroyed!");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity());
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(),
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i("buildGoogleApiClient", "Building GoogleApiClient");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}
```

FusedLocation.java

```
public interface FusedLocation extends NativeInterface{
    public void getFusedLocationPermission();
    public void fusedLocation();
}
```

MyApplication.java

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.show();

    Button btn = new Button("ask for permission");
    FusedLocation fl = (FusedLocation) NativeLookup.create(FusedLocation.class);

    Button btn1 = new Button("fused network");
    hi.add(btn1);
    btn1.addActionListener(e->{
        if (fl != null && fl.isSupported()) {
            fl.getFusedLocationPermission();
            fl.fusedLocation();
            System.out.println("fusedLocation");
        }
    });
}
```

PS. permission for location (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) succeeds. The main issue I've got is onConnected() and other implemented methods are not called. Thankyou

**cn1 Location manager**: this is not giving quite a performance as the native fused location provider

```
public final void checkGPS() {
    if (Display.getInstance().getLocationManager().isGPSDetectionSupported()) {
        if (Display.getInstance().getLocationManager().isGPSEnabled()) {
            InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
            final Dialog ipDlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
            //Cancel after 20 seconds
            Location loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocationSync(20000);
            ipDlg.dispose();
            if (loc != null) {
                lat = loc.getLatitude();
                lng = loc.getLongitude();
                Dialog.show("location", "lat: " + lat + " lon: " + lng, "ok", null);
            } else {
                Dialog.show("GPS error", "Your location could not be found, please try going outside for a better GPS signal", "Ok", null);
            }
        } else {
            Dialog.show("GPS disabled", "AppName needs access to GPS. Please enable GPS", "Ok", null);
        }
    } else {
        Dialog.show("Warning", "GPS is not supported in your device", "ok", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug on the device thru Android Studio?

Comment: yeahh I debugged it in android studio

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you aren't using the location listener which uses fused location internally when play services is enabled (the default).

You asked for permissions in the XML but didn't use the Android 6+ permissions which need [a different syntax](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/marshmallow-permissions-in-the-simulator-and-native-code.html). Again, if you just use the location API this is all seamless...

Comment: In most cases, fused location gives better battery performance, as well as more appropriate accuracy. Actually I've used LocationManager of cn1. But it is frequently returning null value. So what I want to do is if cn1 LocationManager gives null, I'm using fused Location. I've tested it in native android and I'm quite impressed.

Comment: I've mentioned above I've done Android 6+ permissions, just didn't show the code above(ok I've added that too now). Do we have fused location in cn1? Can you make it a bit clear? By the way, I'm confused why doesn't GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks methods working ? (for eg: public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) doesn't work.

Comment: If you leave Codename One as the default and use our location listener fused location is used by default so you don't need any native code see https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/location/AndroidLocationPlayServiceManager.java

Comment: Cool but cn1 location manager often gives null value, where as native fuse location provider seldom gives null. Why is that? Plz have a look at the code I've used at the bottom of the question above. If smth is wrong there. Thankyou

Comment: Which build hints do you have for android?

Comment: I've tried with or without ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in build hints. In the device location setting we can choose 1) GPS, Wifi and mobile networks (or high accuracy in other devices). 2)Wifi and mobile networks 3)GPS only. If I choose Wifi and mobile networks, it doesnt work in cn1 location manager. What I want is that if the GPS is not available or null, it should use Wifi, if wifi is not available it should use mobile networks. In native android (fused location provider), it works but not in cn1 location manager

Comment: Try using the listener approach which will work better for fuse location with our API. You won't get nulls and it should take seconds at most